# reactJS useState infinite loop or not updated at all

Tags: reactjs

I have problems getting useState behave correctly.

I want to hide or show a sub element dependent of a calculation which is dependant on the previous state.

When I run it like this, it causes an infinite re-render:

```
export function PersonWidget(props: Props) {
    const store = useTableState();

    const [positionsVorschlagVisible, setPositionsVorschlagVisible] = React.useState(false);

    var positionsVorschlag = calculatePositionsvorschlag(
        convertTokenToDTOToken(store.previousTokens),
        convertTokenToDTOToken(store.tokens),
        props.tokenId,
        positionsVorschlagVisible.valueOf()
    );

    // this causes infinite loop
    setPositionsVorschlagVisible(visible => 
            (positionsVorschlagVisible && positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.keep) || positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.show);

    return (
        <div style={styles}>
            {positionsVorschlagVisible &&
                <PositionsVorschlag />
            }             
            <Rente />
        </div>
    )

}
```

So I tried to place setting the state inside `useEffect`, but then it's not called anymore after initial rendering:

```
    // not called anymore after initial rendering
    useEffect(() => {
        setPositionsVorschlagVisible(visible => 
            (positionsVorschlagVisible && positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.keep) || positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.show);
    }, [positionsVorschlagVisible]);
```

**Why isn't the component re-rendered even if `positionsVorschlagVisible` has changed? Am I using `useEffect` or `useState` wrong?**

Just as a side note, (i don't know if it matters here), the parent component renders those PersonWidgets depenant of change in a mobx store:

```
export const Screen = observer((): React.ReactElement => {
    const store = useTableState();

    var personTokens = store.tokens.filter(token => token.type === 'person');

    return (<div style={ScreenStyles}>
        {personTokens.map((personToken => {
            return (
                <div key={personToken.id} style={{ position: 'absolute', top: personToken.center.y, left: personToken.center.x }}>
                    <PersonWidget tokenId={personToken.id}/>
                </div>
            )
        }))}

    </div>)

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution for my problem, but I don't know if it's how React should be used.

Making `props` the dependency of useEffect did it. Funny thing is that this has nothing to do with the value i'm changing, it's only the identification of the rendered PersonWidget and holds the `tokenId`. (See parent component)

Can someone explain that? Is it because of the fact that I have mutliple renders of the same component, which is 'only' a function and not a class instance?

PersonWidget.tsx

```
interface Props {
    tokenId: number;
}

export function PersonWidget(props: Props) {
    console.log('PersonWidget ' + props.tokenId + " rendering");
    
    const store = useTableState();
    const [positionsVorschlagVisible, setPositionsVorschlagVisible] = useState(false);

    var positionsVorschlag = calculatePositionsvorschlag(
        convertTokenToDTOToken(store.previousTokens),
        convertTokenToDTOToken(store.tokens),
        props.tokenId,
        positionsVorschlagVisible
    );

    useEffect(() =>  {
        setPositionsVorschlagVisible((positionsVorschlagVisible && positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.keep) || positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.show);
    }, [props]);  ///// <----- THIS was the missing piece!!

   return (
        <div>
            {positionsVorschlagVisible &&
                <PositionsVorschlag />
            }
            <Rente />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Parent component:

```
//[...]
 return (<div>
        {personTokens.map((personToken => {
            return (
                <div key={personToken.id}>
                    <PersonWidget tokenId={personToken.id} />
                </div>
            )
        }))}

    </div>)
//[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can have a check to

```js
visible => (positionsVorschlagVisible && positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.keep) || positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.show);
```

Does this arrow function really change the value of `positionsVorschlagVisible` ?

If you are sure that it is result a differnet value, then this is will alos cause infinite loop

```js
 // not called anymore after initial rendering
    useEffect(() => {
        setPositionsVorschlagVisible(visible => 
            (positionsVorschlagVisible && positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.keep) || positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.show);
    }, [positionsVorschlagVisible]);
```

#### Recommand

Think about your `positionsVorschlagVisible`'s dependency. And add the `setPositionsVorschlagVisible` to its `useEffect()`'s dependency. like this

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        setPositionsVorschlagVisible(visible => 
            (positionsVorschlagVisible && positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.keep) || positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.show);
       //  dependency of PositionsVorschlagVisible
    }, [dependencyOfPositionsVorschlagVisible]);
```

---

Some reference:
[One way data flow](https://tkssharma.gitbook.io/react-training/day-01/react-js-3-principles/one-way-data-flow)
[stack overflow's other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74055745/error-when-accessing-data-from-an-api-in-react/74055971#74055971)

Answer (score 0):

I think you must add setPositionsVorschlagVisible() to an useEffect, otherwise when the state is changed, setPositionsVorschlagVisible() will always be called again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you will not change value/s from dependency array inside useEffect
This is causing the loop

```
 useEffect(() => {
    setPositionsVorschlagVisible(visible => 
        (positionsVorschlagVisible && positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.keep) || positionsVorschlag.showAction === showAction.show);
}, [positionsVorschlagVisible]); <--- this is updating after the useEffect is compleated because useState is asynchronous
```